# Group a HTML tabulation from multidimensional array with data driven documents

Tags: javascript, d3.js, multidimensional-array, data-visualization

Folks,

I want to group the array elements for each of the child elements for the respective parent elements, Can we do this in data driven documents js?

Here is my JSON data.

http://jsfiddle.net/maryhansen/d9wgnbdd/

My html looks like below,

```
        d3.json("Udashboard.json", function (error,data) {

            function tabulate(data, columns) {
                var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
                var thead = table.append('thead')
                var tbody = table.append('tbody');

            // append the header row
            thead.append('tr')
            .selectAll('th')
            .data(columns).enter()
            .append('th')
            .text(function (column) { return column; });

            // create a row for each object in the data
            var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
            .data(data.objects)
            .enter()
            .append('tr');

            // create a cell in each row for each column
            var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
            .data(function (row) {
                return columns.map(function (column) {
                    return {column: column, value: row.officetype[column]};

                });
            })
            .enter()
            .append('td')
            .text(function (d) { return d.value; });  

            return table;
        }

        console.log (data);
        // render the table(s) 
    var peopleTable = tabulate(data, ['code']); // single column table

       // uppercase the column headers
       peopleTable.selectAll("thead th")
       .text(function(column) {
        return column.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + column.substr(1);
    });

    });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

*Updated to reflect a multi-column table with data from different parts of the JSON hierarchy.*

This is an attempt at parsing your rather complex JSON. For this example, d3.json has been removed because it is not using an external file, but you can add this back in if required and change `tabulate(myJSON, ....;` back to `tabulate(data, ...`

E.g.

```
d3.json('/api/data.json', function (error,data) {
    function tabulate(data, columns) {
         // etc etc as per snippet below
    }

    var columnFields = [ { id: "ID", key: "id" },
                         { id: "Interest", key: "interest" },
                         { id: "Loan Amount", key: "loan.amount" },
                         { id: "Code", key: "loan.grouploan[0].gl.groupoffice.code" },
                         { id: "Name", key: "loan.grouploan[0].gl.groupoffice.name" } ];

    // render the table(s)
    var groupOfficeTable = tabulate(myJSON, columnFields); // multi column table    
});
```

Note that it retrieves the data by drilling down to `.objects.loan.grouploan[0].gl.groupoffice`. You will need to modify this code if there is more than one grouploan.

```js
var myJSON = {
        "meta" : {
            "limit" : 200,
            "next" : "/api/v1/loandcb/?limit=200&offset=200",
            "offset" : 0,
            "previous" : null,
            "total_count" : 22374
        },
        "objects" : [{
                "collections" : 0.0,
                "id" : 2081041,
                "interest" : 916.32,
                "loan" : {
                    "amount" : 225000.0,
                    "approval_date" : "2006-05-02T00:00:00",
                    "grouploan" : [{
                            "gl" : {
                                "go" : "C1030", 
                                "groupoffice" : {
                                    "code" : "C1030",
                                    "name" : "MANNARGUDI",
                                    "officeparent" : {
                                        "code" : "BN110", 
                                        "name" : "MANNARGUDI",
                                        "officeparent" : {
                                            "code" : "TJR",
                                            "name" : "TANJORE",
                                            "officeparent" : {
                                                "code" : "CRP",
                                                "name" : "CORPORATE",
                                                "officeparent" : null,
                                                "oficecode" : null,
                                                "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/office/1/"
                                            },
                                            "oficecode" : "CRP",
                                            "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/office/344/"
                                        },
                                        "oficecode" : "TJR",
                                        "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/office/19/"
                                    },
                                    "oficecode" : "BN110",
                                    "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/office/86/"
                                },
                                "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/group/5190/"
                            },
                            "id" : 1432,
                            "last_modified_date" : "2013-04-14T12:42:39.951000",
                            "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/grouploan/1432/"
                        }
                    ],
                    "product" : {
                        "code" : "ATL",
                        "id" : "2",
                        "resource_uri" : ""
                    },
                    "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/entityloan/1/"
                },
                "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/loandcb/2081041/"
            }, {
                "collections" : 0.0,
                "id" : 2081042,
                "interest" : 212.05,
                "loan" : {
                    "amount" : 237500.0,
                    "approval_date" : "2006-05-02T00:00:00",
                    "grouploan" : [{
                            "gl" : {
                                "go" : "C1088",
                                "groupoffice" : {
                                    "code" : "C1088",
                                    "name" : "TRICHY",
                                    "officeparent" : {
                                        "code" : "BN128",
                                        "name" : "TRICHY",
                                        "officeparent" : {
                                            "code" : "TRY",
                                            "name" : "TRICHY",
                                            "officeparent" : {
                                                "code" : "CRP",
                                                "name" : "CORPORATE",
                                                "officeparent" : null,
                                                "oficecode" : null,
                                                "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/office/1/"
                                            },
                                            "oficecode" : "CRP",
                                            "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/office/11/"
                                        },
                                        "oficecode" : "TRY",
                                        "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/office/36/"
                                    },
                                    "oficecode" : "BN128",
                                    "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/office/127/"
                                },
                                "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/group/3260/"
                            },
                            "id" : 907,
                            "last_modified_date" : "2013-04-14T12:42:39.951000",
                            "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/grouploan/907/"
                        }
                    ],
                    "product" : {
                        "code" : "ATL",
                        "id" : "2",
                        "resource_uri" : ""
                    },
                    "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/entityloan/2/"
                },
                "resource_uri" : "/api/v1/loandcb/2081042/"
            }
        ]
    };

function tabulate(data, columns) {
  var table = d3.select('body').append('table')
  var thead = table.append('thead')
  var tbody = table.append('tbody');
 
  // append the header row
  thead.append('tr')
    .selectAll('th')
    .data(columns).enter()
    .append('th')
      .text(function (column) { return column.id; });
 
  // create a row for each object in the data
  var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
    .data(data.objects)
    .enter()
    .append('tr');
 
  // create a cell in each row for each column
  var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
    .data(function (row) {
      return columns.map(function (column) {
        return { column: column.id, value: eval('row.'+column.key) };
      });
    })
    .enter()
    .append('td')
      .text(function (d) { return d.value; });
 
   return table;
}

var columnFields = [ { id: "ID", key: "id" },
                     { id: "Interest", key: "interest" },
                     { id: "Loan Amount", key: "loan.amount" },
                     { id: "Code", key: "loan.grouploan[0].gl.groupoffice.code" },
                     { id: "Name", key: "loan.grouploan[0].gl.groupoffice.name" } ];

 // render the table(s)
tabulate(myJSON, columnFields); // multi column table
```

```css
td, th {
  padding: 1px 4px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes - you can use d3.json to retrieve JSON from the server. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @mccannf. You saved my time a lot. Planned to use the same way as you updated the answer. Cheers.

Comment: Updated with those values also.

Comment: I am able get the output table when using json as a variable in this html page's script, but can't get the output when I tried with the json file from outside. FYI Updated my question

Comment: Must be a different problem. If you put `console.log (data);` before the `tabulate` call does it show the JSON data in the console?

Comment: Is this possible to group the child elements based on the parental elements?  I updated my question with JSON.

Comment: on the above JSON (http://jsfiddle.net/maryhansen/d9wgnbdd/), element officetype has only one array and in next parent it has 6 arrays inner. So I cant use      { id: "C_Code", key: "officetype[1].code" }, to get the elements in table, I am able to get the first result only by using    { id: "C_Code", key: "officetype[0].corp.code" }, Reason is first officetype element has only one inner array and the next officetype elements having multiple inner arrays. Can you give any ideas to handle this problem?